# Adding Event Hub as Subscriber to Event Grid Topic

Tags: azure, azure-eventhub, azure-eventgrid

I have a use case to add an event hub as a subscriber to an event grid domain topic.

Here event grid domain & event hub resides in 2 different Azure subscription (protected by same tenant)

How to create a event grid domain topic subscription to connect to event hub via az cli command ?

Can this be done just with SPN which has access to both these resources or should we use managed identity ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to create the Azure Event Grid domain topic Subscription to connect to Event Hub using Azure CLI Cmdlets - without managed identity:

Followed this [MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/eventgrid/domain/topic/event-subscription?view=azure-cli-latest#az-eventgrid-domain-topic-event-subscription-create) for the below cmdlets:

```
az account set --subscription <my-dev-subscriptionid>
az eventgrid domain create -g KrishDev-RG --name hedomain1 -l westus2 - Done 1
az eventgrid domain topic create -g KrishDev-RG --domain-name hedomain1 --name hedomain1topic1
az account set --subscription <my-prod-subscriptionid>

az eventhubs namespace create --name heventhubns01 --resource-group Krishprod-RG -l westus2
az eventhubs eventhub create --name hevhns01hub --resource-group Krishprod-RG --namespace-name heventhubns01
```

[image]

```
az eventgrid domain topic event-subscription create --name kes1 \
    -g Krishprod-RG --domain-name hedomain1 --domain-topic-name hedomain1topic1 \
    --endpoint <eventhub-endpoint>
```

[image]

**Result**:

[image]